# AJDT Advice Marker Configuration for Maven Defined Aspects

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, ajdt

Currently, I have a Maven project which inherits from a parent pom defining two aspect jars.  The advice markers are displayed for both aspect jars via the m2eclipse AJDT integration.

However, in this case, I only want advice markers displayed for one of the aspect jars, but I don’t seem to be able to achieve this.  I’ve looked at the ‘Configure Advice Markers’ dialog, however this only seems to allow configuration of markers related to aspects defined within that project, not ones defined in external jars.

Is there way to achieve this filtering of advice markers when using external jars?

I’m using:

1. m2eclipse 0.9.8
2. AJDT 2.0.0
3. Eclipse 3.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving feed back from Andrew Eisenberg here http://www.eclipse.org/newsportal/article.php?id=2130&group=eclipse.technology.ajdt, this isn't possible with the current release.